# Help automating updating of aliases for sendmail

Tags: cron, watch

Currently I have a `crontab` entry that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/sendmail stop
/etc/init.d/sendmail start
/usr/bin/newaliases
```

In the category of "learn something new every day", I just came across `watch` (http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html), and am wondering how to implement the updating of the `sendmail` aliases database via watching `/etc/aliases` for changes, rather than just blindly bouncing `smtpd` every day whether or not an update has occurred.

What is the right way of going about this, and should it still be run as a `crontab` entry, or can it be more-or-less daemonized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Linux, there's [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=about&lang=en), and [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). In a manner similar to cron, incron can be configured to watch for filesystem change events (such as changes to configuration files like `/etc/aliases`), and to run processes in response.

Comment: I am on Linux (Ubuntu and CentOS) at the moment - these look pretty promising